# Datetime current year and month in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I must have the current year and month in datetime.

I use this:

```
datem = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m")
datem = datetime.strptime(datem, "%Y-%m")
```

Is there maybe another way?

Comment: do you mean `date.today().strftime("%Y-%m")`?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Use:

```
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today()
datem = datetime(today.year, today.month, 1)
```

I assume you want the first of the month.

Comment: @user3778327: `today` variable already has the current year and month.

Comment: For this solution, be sure to use `from datetime import datetime` rather than simply `import datetime`

Comment: @jpobst I'm using Python 3.8.1 & datetime-4.3 zope.interface-4.7.1, and the above code (with **import datetime**) works for me. If I write **from datetime import datetime**, it throws me *AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'*

Answer (score 301):

Try this solution:

```
from datetime import datetime

current_second = datetime.now().second
current_minute = datetime.now().minute
current_hour = datetime.now().hour

current_day = datetime.now().day
current_month = datetime.now().month
current_year = datetime.now().year
```

Comment: Works, thanks! Is there an advantage over `.now()` rather than `.today()` as used in other answers? The `now()` function is shorter, it's more commonly used... but is there any reason to use one over the other when all one wants to know is [what year it is?](https://giphy.com/gifs/meme-swimming-polar-bear-O1VL59MhotKlW/fullscreen)

Comment: @hashlash Thanks! To save others a click: no, not really

Comment: what does `from datetime` do and why do you need it?

Comment: @Cadoiz - The datetime package has a few submodules - the `date` submodule (`from datetime import date`) which just deals with dates, the `time` submodule which deals with times, and the unfortunately-named `datetime` submodule  which does both.  There's also `timedelta` and `tzinfo` in there.   One could just `import datetime` to get the whole package with all the submodules, but then method calls would look like `datetime.datetime.now()` or `datetime.date.today()`.  Typically, it's nicer for several reasons to import just the components you need.

Comment: This answer suffers from a potential issue if the time is almost exactly midnight. One variable could contain a value from one day and another could contain one from the next day if the day rolls over during the milliseconds between statements. Save the `now()` value in a variable then extract the parts from that variables values. This will produce a consistent result. See @llogiq 's answer.

Answer (score 108):

Use:

```
from datetime import datetime

current_month = datetime.now().strftime('%m') # 02 This is 0 padded
current_month_text = datetime.now().strftime('%h') # Feb
current_month_text = datetime.now().strftime('%B') # February

current_day = datetime.now().strftime('%d')   # 23 This is also padded
current_day_text = datetime.now().strftime('%a')  # Fri
current_day_full_text = datetime.now().strftime('%A')  # Friday

current_weekday_day_of_today = datetime.now().strftime('%w') # 5  Where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday.

current_year_full = datetime.now().strftime('%Y')  # 2018
current_year_short = datetime.now().strftime('%y')  # 18 without century

current_second= datetime.now().strftime('%S') # 53
current_minute = datetime.now().strftime('%M') # 38
current_hour = datetime.now().strftime('%H') # 16 like 4pm
current_hour = datetime.now().strftime('%I') # 04 pm

current_hour_am_pm = datetime.now().strftime('%p') # 4 pm

current_microseconds = datetime.now().strftime('%f') # 623596 Rarely we need.

current_timzone = datetime.now().strftime('%Z') # UTC, EST, CST etc. (empty string if the object is naive).
```

Reference: *[8.1.7. strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)*

Reference: *[strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)*

The above things are useful for any date parsing, not only now or today. It can be useful for any date parsing.

e.g.

```
my_date = "23-02-2018 00:00:00"

datetime.strptime(str(my_date),'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00:00')

datetime.strptime(str(my_date),'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%m')
```

And so on...

Comment: See my comment on @Gaurav Dave 's answer.

Answer (score 20):

The question asks to use `datetime` specifically.

This is a way that uses `datetime` only:

```
from datetime import datetime
year = datetime.now().year
month = datetime.now().month
```

Answer (score 17):

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.today().month
2
>>> date.today().year
2020
>>> date.today().day
13
```

Answer (score 16):

Late answer, but you can also use:

```
import time
ym = time.strftime("%Y-%m")
# 2024-02
```

Comment: Late, but not wrong, and even clear than using datetime. Thanks :).

Answer (score 10):

You can write [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28189527/2988730) as a one-liner using [`date.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace):

```
datem = datetime.today().replace(day=1)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can always use a sub-string method:

```
import datetime;

today = str(datetime.date.today());
curr_year = int(today[:4]);
curr_month = int(today[5:7]);
```

This will get you the current month and year in integer format. If you want them to be strings you simply have to remove the " int " precedence while assigning values to the variables `curr_year` and `curr_month`.

Comment: This is bad. Why need to cast it then do a string manipulation? ```datetime.datetime.now().month``` is better.

Answer (score 2):

In case you'd like to print a calendar in Python, this works well:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import calendar

print(calendar.month(dt.today().year, dt.today().month))
```

or

```
year = 2023
month = 6
print(calendar.month(year, month)
```

This renders a little calendar graphic:
[Calendar for June 2023](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbhjG.png)

Answer (score 0):

using the regular expression extract the date and time from the string then convert the string date to a datetimeindex using strptime

```
import re

s = "Audio was recorded at 21:50:00 02/07/2019 (UTC) by device 243B1F05 at gain setting 2 while battery state was 3.6V."

t = re.search(' (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}) ', s).group(1)

date=datetime.datetime.strptime(t,'%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%Y')
print(type(date))
```