# How to extract the current month from this string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-search

In the given code below I want to get the current month (October if I run it today) instead of `"current_month"` in `monthpage` which is `"file/monthly/current_month"`.

How can it be done?

```py
def CurrentMonth(self):  
    monthpage = "file/monthly/current_month"
    page = Page
    old_text = page.get(get_redirect=True)
```

Comment: What is your data like?

Comment: I don't know if I get your question correctly, but if you want the month that the program is executed in, refer to this post about how to use the `datetime` library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071886/how-to-get-current-time-in-python-and-break-up-into-year-month-day-hour-minu

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189442/datetime-current-year-and-month-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
monthpage.replace('current_month',now.strftime("%B"))
```

It replaces the `"current_month"` string in `monthpage` variable with actual current month name

Comment: %b can be used also if you want abbreviated month like 'Oct'.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Use the datetime library !!

```
import datetime
mydate = datetime.datetime.now()
mydate.strftime("%B")
```

Comment: In this case, the month can simply be accessed by `mydate.month`

Comment: That just gives you the month number (10 for October)

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way :

```
import datetime
current_month = datetime.now().month()
```