# sum up purchases of current year and month

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, date

I need to add the purchases of users in a list with the following conditions:

"Those customers who have a sum of purchases in the current year of 15,000 or more are entitled to a 20% discount. If they have also spent 3000 or more in the current month, they have an additional 15%."

The list is the following:

```
purchases=[{"id": "123", 'price':16000, 'date': "(2022, 3, 12)"},{"id": "123", 'price':4000, 'date': "(2022, 11, 20)"}]
```

I don't know how to add up the purchases in the current year and month, if someone can help :)

Comment: What have you tried? Nobody just knows these things, one needs to look for a solution, try to write one that matches their specific problem, and then if there's problems with the solution, ask about those specific problems on StackOverflow. "How to solve this problem with code" is not [on topic for StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Try to [make an honest attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) at solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current year and month from `datetime.date.today()` (See [Datetime current year and month in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189442/datetime-current-year-and-month-in-python))

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

# Current year: today.year
# Current month today.month
```

Iterate over each element of `purchases`. The `"date"` key in each element tells you the date for that purchase. It's annoying that the value at this key is a string representation of a tuple, but we can parse it using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

The first element of this tuple is the year for the purchase. The second element is the month. So we need to check if these values match the values for `today`, and add to the corresponding totals:

```
import ast

total_month = 0
total_year = 0

for purchase in purchases:
    p_date = ast.literal_eval(purchase["date"])
    if p_date[0] == today.year:
        total_year += purchase["price"]
    if p_date[1] == today.month:
        total_month += purchase["price"]
```

And after we've looked through all purchases, we can check our criteria:

```
if total_year >= 15_000:
    print("20% discount")
    if total_month >= 3000:
        print("Extra 15% discount")
```